# How to get rid of "Input limit reached. [...]" warning

Tags: starcraft-2

This warning incessantly pops up every time I try to navigate within the menus and such, and this drives the living hell out of me.

How do you get rid of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that it is related to having a very large friends list. They are aware of it as a current bug and are going to be addressing it.

http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2301630502

Comment: Interesting. I do have a sizable friends list. Might do some "unfriending" business later just to test :D

Comment: this is absolutely true.  I read this on the blizzard forums the other day, sized down my friends list, and now I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: @kazzmalla Indeed. I've done that as well, and sure enough, it worked.

Comment: Reducing the size of friend list doesn't seem to help ease the problem in my case. I still have this annoying pop out box from time to time. Hope Blizzard can fix this bug asap.